# How to solve the maven xmlbeans plugin dependency issue

Tags: java, maven

I am using maven xmlbeans 2.5.0 plugin. I am not able to run `mvn clean` command . I am getting the below issue. can anyone help me to sort out this issue

```
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:2.5.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.5.0: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:pom:2.5.0 from/to nexus (https://nexus.tuinteractive.com/content/groups/public): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:2.5.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.5.0
```

Comment: it is available in central maven repository, your maven has been configured to proxy some repositories or is <repository> tag set in your pom.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

As per http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.codehaus.mojo%22%20AND%20a%3A%22xmlbeans-maven-plugin%22

latest version of xmlbeans-maven-plugin is 2.3.3 and looks like you have configured version as 2.5.0

Would you mind sharing your plugin configuration.